# error integrating google api with iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, youtube-api, gdata-api

I am developing a cocos2d app and I need to integrate youtube API to upload a video to the youtube.
I have integrated gdata api downloaded from [here](http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/files/gdata-objectivec-client-1.11.0.zip).And changed the project settings as follows.

set
Other Linker Flags:
 -lxml2

Other C Flags:
-DDEBUG=1

C Language Dialect:
C99 [-std=c99]

added
Header Search Paths:
/usr/include/libxml2
and added libxml2.dlyb

But when I build the project getting the following error messages

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      -[GDataOAuthSignIn startReachabilityCheck] in GDataOAuthSignIn.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[GDataOAuthSignIn startReachabilityCheck] in GDataOAuthSignIn.o
      -[GDataOAuthSignIn stopReachabilityCheck] in GDataOAuthSignIn.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[GDataOAuthSignIn startReachabilityCheck] in GDataOAuthSignIn.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[GDataOAuthSignIn stopReachabilityCheck] in GDataOAuthSignIn.o
  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:
      -[GDataOAuthKeychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
  "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:
      -[GDataOAuthKeychain removePasswordForService:account:error:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
  "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:
      -[GDataOAuthKeychain setPassword:forService:account:error:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:
      +[GDataOAuthKeychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kSecAttrGeneric", referenced from:
      +[GDataOAuthKeychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:
      +[GDataOAuthKeychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kSecClass", referenced from:
      +[GDataOAuthKeychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:
      +[GDataOAuthKeychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kSecMatchLimit", referenced from:
      -[GDataOAuthKeychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kSecMatchLimitOne", referenced from:
      -[GDataOAuthKeychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kSecReturnData", referenced from:
      -[GDataOAuthKeychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:
      -[GDataOAuthKeychain setPassword:forService:account:error:] in GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anybody know how to solve this problem
If any additional settings needed for the project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include this framework **`SystemConfiguration.framework`**